# After adding javascript, all links in my webpage are dead

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making an website which has menu and image slides. But when I add javascript for animation, everything above the images are dead. How to fix that?
HTML code:

```
<head>
    <title>Water Solutions</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/common.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/index.css">
    <script src="JS/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="showSlides()">
    <div class = "navbar">
        <div id = "Header">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="#"><img src="Images/onlinelogomaker-122816-1814-1991.png"></a>
            </div>
            <nav id = "Menu">
                <ul id = "Menu-Items">
                    <li class="Item"><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slideshow-container">
        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img src="Images/Image1.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img src="Images/Image2.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img src="Images/Image3.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </div>
    </div><br>

</body>
```

Now to the javascript part:

```
var slideIndex = 0;
function showSlides(){
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex >= slides.length) {
        slideIndex=0;
    }

    slides[slideIndex].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(showSlides, 5000);
}
```

The css files:(index.css)

```
.mySlides{
    display: none;
}
.slideshow-container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px 0;
}



/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}
```

common.css:

```
body{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.Header{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 120px;
    height: 120px;
}

#Menu-Items{
    float: right;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
#Menu-Items li{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 20px 10px ;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    line-height: normal;
}

.logo{
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    margin: 0px 15px 15px 0;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

a:active{
    color: deepskyblue;
}

a:hover{
    color: deepskyblue;
}

input[type=text] {
    width: 130px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: white;
    background-position: 10px 10px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

Everything is alive if I remove the javascript part. Is it due to the `body onload`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: any errors in the developer tools console?

Comment: can you please create a fiddle?

Comment: What do you mean by *dead*? Nothing is clickable anymore? Then the slider is probably on top of your navigation.

Comment: What do you mean by 'dead'? Please be clear when describing behaviour, and make sure to add any error information you may get from the console (F12).

Comment: @JaromandaX no errors  in the developer tools console

Comment: By dead I mean nothing is clickable anymore, even when I move the cursor over them and inspect them, they behave like they don't exist.

Comment: Your code as is works fine - is there anything you've neglected to include that may be important i.e. the CSS may be doing something we can't see with z-index, relative/absolute/fixed positioning etc

Comment: You are displaying the image as a block outside of the for loop and you are setting the property display none to every slide each time, rewrite your javascript differently

Comment: @mnemosdev - how does that effect the links in the div class="navbar" ?

Comment: @JaromandaX yeah sorry, doesn't.

Comment: @d1729 try to change the onload and set it into the slideshow-container, tell us if it changes anything

Comment: This is more likely a CSS issue where some container overlaps the links

Comment: op could post the css files with the specific stylings

Comment: @mnemosdev did that and images don't show up anymore but links start working

Comment: posted the css ..take a look

Comment: @d1729 Try starting the event directly in your javascript like document.onload = function(){ your javascript } so you avoid having any logic in the view and it might fix the problem.

Comment: Maybe your uncleared float in the menu is causing this issue. Clearing it with a clearfix may help. `#Menu:after { content:''; clear: both; display: table; }`

Comment: @mnemosdev still nothing changes.. same thing. P.S: My first time designing a proper website.

Comment: @KilianStinson that fixed it.... Thanks

Comment: @d1729 Added as an answer.

Comment: @mnemosdev http://stackoverflow.com/a/588048/295783

Comment: Please create a working fiddle, it'll be easier to find a solution that way.

Answer (score 2):

Your uncleared float in the menu is causing this issue. Clearing it with a clearfix should fix this.

```
#Menu:after { 
    content:''; 
    clear: both; 
    display: table; 
}
```

Adding a `pseudo-element` with `clear: both` lets the document flow recognize the height of your `#Menu` and renders the following elements correctly after your navigation and not on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

Add `z-index: 999;` in your CSS, in the `#Menu-Items li`

Comment: even if I remove timeout, the animation goes away but links are still not clickable

Answer (score -1):

Try moving the script tag after body tag.

Check the following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhatnagar018/19449j19/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Water Solutions</title>
  </head>

  <body onload="showSlides()">
    <div class="navbar">
      <div id="Header">
        <div class="logo">
          <a href="#"><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"></a>
        </div>
        <nav id="Menu">
          <ul id="Menu-Items">
            <li class="Item"><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slideshow-container">
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/d2/6c/51/d26c511a38b62ec9a2faf464b798e755.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/75/b5/f4/75b5f40a2d4319f1f9a8fe8655108106.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSkkEkaVL8vInMmnwwLobcNZT3VSRwbZcrwVVAyVHjHT_J4BwUcZA" style="width:100%">
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>

  </body>

  <script>
    var slideIndex = 0;

    function showSlides() {
      console.log('Hi');
      var i;
      var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      slideIndex++;
      if (slideIndex >= slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 0;
      }
      slides[slideIndex].style.display = "block";
      setTimeout(showSlides, 5000);
    }

  </script>

</html>
```

Comment: Same thing...nothing improves

Comment: Nothing goes after the body tag.

Comment: @mplungjan I have read many articles which suggests to put scripts at the end of the body.
Can you please tell me where we should put it?

Comment: At the END of the body is not AFTER the body